# Type-C USB-C trigger - Set lowest voltage allowed

Tags: usb

Is it possible to set the lowest voltage allowed to output at 12 or 20 volts? In other terms, stop it from outputting 5v(Output 12v or 20v only). Using the USB-c trigger ZYPDS from here (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32969919810.html). Other people will be using a project im working on that uses this usb-c trigger to supply 12 volt to an LED driver. If they accidentally use a standard (Type A) USB to USB-c wall adapter, it will damage the LED driver im using which cannot operate at 5v. Any Suggestions? The part number on the chip being used on the USB-c trigger is ip2721. I cannot read chines but here is the datasheet (http://www.szjuquan.com/upload_files/qb_sell_/pdf/IP2721.pdf).[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Zener diode.  Ignore all those voltage regulator tutorials, since that's not how you would be using it.  Instead by simply whacking it in series, without a resistor, you are using it as a gate.  I would almost consider using a 9v Zener in this application, provided the chip never outputs 9v.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it floating.

I've just "read" the Chinese manual, the settings are: 
 * pull down: 5V
 * pull up: 20V 
 * floating: 15V

BTW From my experience the chip isn't very stable.

Comment: What do you mean by "not very stable"?